# Prism insciption

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

In my lab I used a prism with the inscription "F 1.65" on the top. Does anyone know what this means? I think it should have something to do with the focal lenght, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"F" stands for *flint glass* and 1.65 is its index of refraction.